# How to auto assign next letter from a list into a cell depending on value of another?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

Here is a basic sheet with list of days of the month that change according to date in a specified cell, trying to find a way to automatically assign next letter from a list and place it in cell according to what day it is in neighbor cell.

This is the closest I've gotten using IFS:

```
=IFS($B$4:$B$37="MONDAY", SORTN($F$4:$F$7,1,,RANDARRAY(4),),$B$4:$B$37="TUESDAY", SORTN($G$4:$G$7,1,,RANDARRAY(4),), $B$4:$B$37="WEDNESDAY", SORTN($H$4:$H$7,1,,RANDARRAY(4),),$B$4:$B$37="THURSDAY", SORTN($I$4:$I$7,1,,RANDARRAY(4),), $B$4:$B$37="FRIDAY", SORTN($J$4:$J$7,1,,RANDARRAY(4),), $B$4:$B$37="SATURDAY", SORTN($K$4:$K$7,1,,RANDARRAY(4),), $B$4:$B$37="SUNDAY", SORTN($L$4:$L$7,1,,RANDARRAY(4),))
```

This method doesn't choose next in line but randomly chooses from within the range. This could potentially work but one issue is that this can potentially assign same letter three Mondays in a row, another issue is the default "onChange" setting causing data from formulas to change with every edit.

`Description:F3:L7` Alphabet represents (Peoples names or anything else) that are available (to work on those days) & can appear for each day on Calendar found in columns `B:C`. Column `D` in image is currently the expected output. Would need it to change automatically as the calendar changes, "Monday" will not always appear in `B4` when date in `A4` is changed.

FIXED Sheet link (Most wording is in Spanish): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S14Rd_bujRGkCHxLd_gHg6TwQBA_aUCx5LfxOTdqQyE/edit#gid=0

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the logic for achieving your goal from your sample image. So I cannot understand about `find a way to automatically assign next letter from a list and place it in cell according to what day it is in neighbor cell.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, what is `a list`?

Comment: Example: the letter "A" can only be assigned in column D if column B falls on a Monday. List on the right demonstrates what group of letters belongs to each day.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that the cells "F3:L7" are `a list`. But I have to apologize for my poor understanding. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about the logic for your question. From your replying, why "D11" and "D18" are "B" and "C", respectively? By the way, your sample image is the output situation you expect? If it's so, can I ask you about the input situation you expect? By the way, why the cells "L6" and "L7" are the empty?

Comment: Yes this is the expected output. D11 & D18 are "B" &"C" because those were the next times Monday was found in columnB. So scrolling down next time Monday appears it'll be assigned to "D" then as week passes Monday will again be assigned  letter "A". For column L its empty for simple reason that alphabet ended so Y Z will take turns each Sunday.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: How does the date correlate to values in your table in F3:L7

Comment: Imagine F3:L7 as being a changeable list of people who are available to work only on the days that there name appears. With that in mind this list will be updated monthly, so when date in A4 is edited, everything in columns B:C is adjusted automatically. For example: if date in A4 is changed to 4/1/21 B4 will then turn into Thursday April 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! Used an `Arrayformula` to assign a number to each duplicate, got the idea here https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/make-duplicates-to-unique-in-google-sheets/ then using `IFS` formula from description. Link to working sheet will be in description.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function myfunc101() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let [hA,...data]=sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let col={};
  let idx={};
  hA.forEach((h,i)=>{col[h]=i+1;idx[h]=i;})
  let al={};
  data.forEach((r)=>{
    if(!al.hasOwnProperty(r[1])) {
      al[r[1]]=[];
      al[r[1]].push([r[3]])
    } else {
      al[r[1]].push([r[3]])
    }
  });
  let wds=['MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY','SUNDAY'];
  wds.forEach((d)=>{
    sh.getRange(4,col[d+'S'],al[d].length,1).setValues(al[d]);
  });
}
```

Comment: It didn't seem to work, I tried changing to an onEdit function as well but is there another adjustment that can be made? To clarify, the image is the expected output but column D should change when days on left side change.

Comment: If you will give me the data that you have in your spreadsheet in a table then I will debug it and get it running for you.  I'm sure the method is sound but it probably needs some debug.  It develops an object from columns B & D and builds the table for columns f through l.  And please note I will not follow links to spreadsheets.   And note it was not developed to be an onEdit() function.  It's a function you run by clicking on a menu item.  In general, I tend to avoid the use of triggers whenever possible..

Comment: Got it, so I get this error from script as is: Syntax error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...' line: 4 file: Code.gs". The formulas I have in columns B:C is simply as follows =upper(TEXT(C4, "DDDD")) =A4
=upper(TEXT(C5, "DDDD")) =A4+1
=upper(TEXT(C6, "DDDD")) =A4+2. So dates change based on value of A4

Comment: I just want the values that are in your spreadsheet.  I'm not interested in formulas.  I never use them.

Comment: I added the data table above. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Nate Try it again.  I made a couple small corrections and now it's working just run it from the script editor after correcting the sheet name in line 3

Comment: Tried it, I dont understand though, what is supposed to trigger the letters from range F3:L7 to be placed in column D?

Comment: Oh I thought you were taking the data from column D and putting it in the table  F3:L7

Comment: The data in you table is different that the data in your image so it's not clear to me what the logic is in moving from F3:L7 to Column D.  So I will need you to explain that better.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I have a formula in there that changes letters with every edit so was different when I copied table. Ok, so notice "Mondays"  in column D from image & updated table. 1st Monday =A, 2nd Monday=B, 3rd Monday=C, 4th Monday=D etc. Thats how I would want it to happen, in that order. The issue with my formula is that it randomly chooses between A,B,C or D for Mondays, so in column D, three Mondays in a row could potentially have letter A. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Alphabet in Column F:L represents (Peoples names or anything else) that are available (to work on those days). When Start date in column A is changed, it also changes column B, so Mondays will not always be the first to apear on top.

Comment: I think I understand the algorthm for assignment of letters into column D.  I assumed the table is a data input.  So the other question is how do you want this to run.  I understand you are currently using an onEdit() function.  So if you are using an onEdit we only have to change the cells are edited

Comment: I'm thinking everything could rely when editing the date, in this case found in cell A4.